# removing all the space between two ggplots combined with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to stick two plots without any space between theme (so they share one axis).

Given:

```
p1 <- qplot(1,1,xlab="")

p1 <- p1 +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,0,1), "cm"),
        panel.margin=unit(c(1,1,0,1), "cm"))
p2 <- qplot(1,2)

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

Which produces:

[image]

I want to eliminate the white space between the two plots.

I have the impression tweaking heights, as has been done for widths in : [left align two graph edges (ggplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294952/left-align-two-graph-edges-ggplot/13295880#13295880) is the solution, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove the borders from grid.arrange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728272/remove-the-borders-from-grid-arrange)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should provide `plot.margin` for both plots and set negative value for the bottom margin for p1 and upper margin for p2. This will ensure that both plot joins.

```
p1 <-  qplot(1,1,xlab="")+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,-0.5,1), "cm"))
p2 <- qplot(1,2)+
  theme(legend.position="none",
        plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5,1,1,1), "cm"))


grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Worth also mentioning the default plot.margin settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32146933/6924364

Answer (score 0):

try

```
+ labs(x=NULL)
```

OR

```
+ labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
```

to remove the left and bottom margins around the plots (p1, p2) before using grid.arrange

```
p1 <- qplot(1,1)+
 theme_bw() +
 theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
 axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
 plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4),
 panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
 axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"null"),
 axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"null")) +
 labs(x=NULL)
p2 <- qplot(1,2)+
 theme_bw() +
 theme(
 plot.margin = rep(unit(0,"null"),4),
 panel.margin = unit(0,"null"),
 axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"null"),
 axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"null"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

Comment: that's not great either; what if people actually want axis titles? Or legends? Best option would be to properly align the gtables, and there are several posts here that offer more general and reliable solutions

Comment: Mind linking to those better solutions?