# Wider margins for grid.arrange function

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I'm building a composition of plots (created using `ggplot2`) running the function `grid.arrange`. 
Although I have the composition done, **I want the plots not to be so close to the margins**.

I know for other type of plots, the function `par()` allows to modify these distances, but **how can I do this for a composition with `grid.arrange()`?**

Comment: [Change "plot.margin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556068/removing-all-the-space-between-two-ggplots-combined-with-grid-arrange) for your individual plots.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can change the plot margins,

```
pl = replicate(5, ggplot(), FALSE)

grid.arrange(grobs = pl) # default margins
# vs
grid.arrange(grobs= lapply(pl, "+", theme(plot.margin=margin(10,10,10,10))))
```

[image]

Edit: if the intent is to have the plots away from the device's borders, then one should draw in a reduced viewport,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = pl, vp=viewport(width=0.7, height=0.7))
```

[image]